# Error when pointing Geoserver to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a PostGIS database that contains all my GIS data along with metadata. I have it published as a Store in GeoServer. They are both installed on the same windows server 2008r2.

When i try to add layers from the store resource and publish it, i encounter an error at the bottom of the "Data" tab of the resource configuration page. Any ideas what might be my problem?

[image]
When i click on the yellow warning icon i get:
[image]
Here is the error:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [Component id = message] at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2563) at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebComponent.onRender(WebComponent.java:60) at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2361) at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1298) at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1428) at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:1502) at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2361) at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:913) at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.PageRequestTarget.respond(PageRequestTarget.java:63) at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:104) at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1245) at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1316) at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1418) at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:532) at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:356) at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:124) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1124) at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265) at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107) at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149) at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115) at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:73) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115) at org.geoserver.filters.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(ReverseProxyFilter.java:183) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115) at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:41) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1115) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:361) at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766) at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:534) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:864) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:533) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:207) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:403) at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409) at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:522) Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Unable to find resource: featureTypeReloadWarning for component: resource:tabs:panel:theList:1:content [class=org.geoserver.web.data.resource.FeatureResourceConfigurationPanel] at org.apache.wicket.Localizer.getString(Localizer.java:266) at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.getString(StringResourceModel.java:491) at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.load(StringResourceModel.java:633) at org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel.getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:114) at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel$AssignmentWrapper.getObject(StringResourceModel.java:230) at org.apache.wicket.Component.getModelObject(Component.java:1565) at org.apache.wicket.Component.getModelObjectAsString(Component.java:1587) at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label.onComponentTagBody(Label.java:111) at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderComponent(Component.java:2524) ... 73 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bug report stating the following about my exact error:

> This has been reported a number of
>   times already. The nightly builds of
>   the 2.0.x series or the 2.1-RC2
>   release do not suffer from the problem
>   anymore

I will test/verify this and post back if it works.

Comment: Please don't include your own comments as answers, but as 'edits' or 'comments'.  Thanks!

Comment: @WolfOdrade: This is an answer not a comment. If it were a comment it would be placed as a comment. If you need clarification of the answer, it means i need to upgrade to a nightly build of the 2.0.x series or the 2.1-RC2 release. I'm still verifying if this answer is correct or not.